# Why some methods are filtered out after `exposeInMainWorld`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I was trying to expose `fs` to render process by

```js
//proload.js

const { contextBridge } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('NodeAPI', {fs});

// render process

if (NodeAPI.fs.lstatSync('.').isDirectory()) {
...// isDirectory is not a function
}
```

`fs.lstatSync` should return a `Stat` object which has a `isDirectory` method.
But I find out it just returned a plain object.
Is Electron filter methods like this out for security reason?

Comment: Did you find out how to go about with this? I am having the same problem!

Comment: @keechan no. I give up on this approach